# styling facebook button in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

In the dynamic login button i've ._4z_d ._4z_f  class with some padding . And i'm giving him padding through styling tags as

```
._4z_d ._4z_f { 
       padding: 9px 24px !important;
}
```

so as expected my padding is not implemented because button is dynamic and it's original padding is also dynamic . Any help will be quite appreciatable

Comment: <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
                        
                    </fb:login-button>

Comment: @shashank here is the button code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that the button is dynamic shouldn't be a problem for you, try giving it a block box model, I suspect that the button is still inheriting its default box model.

```
._4z_d ._4z_f { 
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 9px 24px !important;
}
```